# Как спрашивать про загрузку файла на сервер?

Tags: php

Есть такой код

```
 <html>
<head>Загрузка  файлов на сервер</head>
<body>
  <form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""  method="post">
  <input  type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000"  />
  <input  type="file" name="uploadFile"/>
  <input  type="submit" name="upload" value="Загрузить"/>
  </form>
      <?php
        print_r($_FILES);

        if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
            $folder       = 'path/to/folder/';
            $uploadedFile = $folder . basename($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'])) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadedFile)) {
                    echo "Файл загружен";
                } else {
                    echo "Во  время загрузки файла произошла ошибка";
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Файл не  загружен';
            }
        }
      ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так и непонятно где вопрос?

Comment: Все равно не загружает

Answer (score 1):

```
$folder = 'path/to/folder/';
if($_FILES['uploadFile']['error'] == 0){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],$folder.$_FILES['uploadFile']['name'])){
        echo "Файл загружен";
    }
}
```